# How to put image in show info window of marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a problem, I don't know to put imagen in window when user touch the marker.
I want to do this[image]

I have this code:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
        .title("Restaurante Pinochio")
        .snippet("C. San Francesc, 4").icon(icon));
```

But now I don't know how to put this image. Any idea?
I hope that somebody help me.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? In particular [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows) and things about `InfoWindowAdapter`?

Comment: Go to this [android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html)